# Present participle phrase?

Tags: participle-phrases

In the sentence:

'He sat FACING THE WALL', is 'facing the wall' a present participle phrase? It is stated in numerous grammar articles from reliable sites that participle phrases must always act as adjectives, adding description to the sentence. For examples, 'Facing the wall, he thought about what he has done wrong.' Here it is used as an adjectival phrase to describe what the person was doing.

However, I believe 'facing the wall' in my example would clearly make more sense if you think of it as an adverbial phrase that modifies the past tense of 'sit'. If so, can it be counted as an exception? Or perhaps it's not a participle phrase but something else entirely. Please elaborate on your answer so that it can be as helpful as possible for future reference. It would be greatly appreciated if you can provide links/citations  in your answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a present participial clause (or gerund-participial clause as it's often called it nowadays). I'd say that _facing the wall_ is predicative, not a complement, but a depictive adjunct referring to the subject "he". In your other example _Facing the wall, he thought about ..._, it's not an adjective clause, but a supplementary adjunct, set apart from the rest of the clause by a comma and a slight pause in speech - a separate unit of information and not a modifier.

Comment: In other words, the gerund participial clause in my first example is still serving as an adjective and not an adverb?

Comment: Well, not an actual adjective of course because that's a part of speech, but an adjunct (many people call it an adverbial). It refers to the subject, like an adjective would, but it is part of the verb phrase. A kind of hybrid really.